Statics and torque equilibrium problem

This is a ladder, which is connected to a wall with a string (at the bottom - F is the tension in the string). It is in equilibrium at 60 degrees. I understand that I have to set the result of the forces in the x and y directions and the result of torques to 0. I'm just a little bit confused about the answer provided in the textbook.
x component equilibrium:
F - F1 = 0
Torque equilibrium:
mg(Length/2)*cos60 - F1(length)sin60 = 0
I'm confused about the y component equilibrium. In the textbook it says:
mg - F2 = 0
But isn't there a y component of the force which is pressing on the wall at the top? Since it's pushing on the wall at an angle, I'm assuming it has an x component F1 and a y component F1*tan(90-60). Why is it not included in the solution?

Did the problem tell you there is friction between the ladder and the vertical wall?

There is no friction. I completely missed that. So because there is no friction, there is no y component right?

Yes. "No friction" means no interaction force component parallel to the surface

Perfect, thank you very much

A vertical wall can only excert a force perpendicular to its surface, like any plane.

In general there could be friction
